# How execute sequelize-cli without overwrite configurations

Tags: node.js, model, migration, sequelize-cli

what best way to execute migrations and seeds on docker with sequelize-cli? Every time i run sequelize-cli init  the configuration files is overwrite and are writes with default configurations and i lose my configurations file write in typescript to json.

Answer (score 0):

i found the better is use sequelize without cli on container. Like that:

```
npx sequelize db:migrate
```